# how to solve Too many arguments for public abstract fun enqueue(responseCallback: Callback): Unit defined in okhttp3.Call

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin, okhttp

I follow this tutorial about kotlin programing language parsing API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W41M9fWf6I&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGfHj1lwxOq67zAJV3e1S9S&index=5,

and for follow about tutorial link in below I use androidx api version 30

but I got stuck at  14:54, about

```
"client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback){

        }"
```

I  got an error at the line (45), in CourseDetailActivity

the error is:

```
Too many arguments for public abstract fun enqueue(responseCallback: Callback): Unit defined in   okhttp3.Call
```

this is my CourseDetailActivity :

```
class CourseDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//        recyclerView_main.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
        recyclerView_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView_main.adapter = CourseDetailAdapter()

        val navbarTitle = intent.getStringExtra(CustumViewHolder.VIDEO_TITLE_KEY)
        supportActionBar?.title = navbarTitle


//        println(courseDetailUrl)

        fetcJson()


    }

    private fun fetcJson() {
        val videoID = intent.getIntExtra(CustumViewHolder.VIDEO_ID_KEY, -1)
        val courseDetailUrl = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/course_detail?id=" + videoID

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(courseDetailUrl).build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback){

        }
    }


    private class CourseDetailAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseLessonViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CourseLessonViewHolder {


            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            val custumView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.course_lesson_row, parent, false)

//            val blueView = View(parent?.context)
//            blueView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
//            blueView.minimumHeight = 50
            return CourseLessonViewHolder(custumView)


        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return 5
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CourseLessonViewHolder, position: Int) {

        }


    }
}

private class CourseLessonViewHolder(val custumView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    (custumView) {

}
```

this is my MainAdapter.kt class :

```
class MainAdapter(val homeFeed: HomeFeed) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustumViewHolder>() {

    val videoTitles = listOf("First Title", "Second", "3rd")

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return homeFeed.videos.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustumViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.video_row, parent, false)
        return CustumViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustumViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val video = homeFeed.videos.get(position)
        holder?.view?.textView_video_title?.text = video.name

        holder?.view?.textview_channel_name?.text =
            video.channel.name + "+" + "20k Views\n" + "2 days ago"

        val thumbnailImageView = holder?.view?.imageView_video_thumbnail

        Picasso.get().load(video.imageUrl).into(thumbnailImageView)


        val channelProfileImageView = holder?.view?.imageView_channel_profile
        Picasso.get().load(video.imageUrl).into(channelProfileImageView)

        holder?.video = video

    }
}

class CustumViewHolder(val view: View, var video: Video? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    companion object {
        val VIDEO_TITLE_KEY = "VIDEO_TITLE"
        val VIDEO_ID_KEY = "VIDEO_ID"
    }

    init {
        view.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(view.context, CourseDetailActivity::class.java)

            intent.putExtra(VIDEO_TITLE_KEY, video?.name)
            intent.putExtra(VIDEO_ID_KEY, video?.id)

            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in anonymous class that implement interface "Callback".

Instead this

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback){

}
```

Use this

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}

    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {}
})
```

Comment: Wow thank you man this worked for me. I made the mistake of placing the curly braces outside the brackets. lol silly me